# Topological Sorting of Basic Blocks in LLVM

Tags: llvm, topological-sort

I would like to be able to get the basic blocks in a function in topological order. There is an iterator available which iterates over the basic blocks in a function, however I am not sure if it does it in topological order. I wasn't able to get the next basic block for a particular basic block and wasn't able to do topological sorting myself.

You can assume there are no loops in the CFG.

Comment: You can assume that there are no loops

Comment: To find a block's successor(s), you can have a look at the TerminatorInstructions (`block.getTerminatorInstruction()`) and see where the CFG branches.

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to a blog post written about this question - http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/09/16/analyzing-function-cfgs-with-llvm/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the general case, this is impossible because BBs don't form a DAG. A topological order is only defined for a DAG - a graph without cycles; BBs within a function may form cycles (loops, etc).

Your best approximation IMHO is to decompose the BB graph into SCCs (Strongly Connected Components). LLVM already has tools to do that: see `include/llvm/ADT/SCCIterator.h`, and also `tools/opt/PrintSCC.cpp`.

The latter, in fact, will already print the SCCs of a function in *reverse* topological order, invoked like this:

```
$ opt -print-cfg-sccs <bitcode file>
```

**Update (16-Sep-2013)**: See also [this blog post](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/09/16/analyzing-function-cfgs-with-llvm/).

Comment: Thanks for the blog post!